# Transfer files from PLC to PC server using FileZilla

Tags: filezilla

How do you connect your PLC to a FileZilla client and transfer files to a server with it? We are using Pheonix Contact PC Worx PLC's and are writing data in the files we want to send to read them afterwards on the PC. Is there a better way?

Comment: What about using OPC/UA and get the data direct from the PLC ? I can see that Phoenix offers OPC/UA components.

Comment: So, there's actually a way to do it with a programm. You have to pass it the source and destination address with Username and password for both. I don't really understand how it works, I'm not used to play with low-level things but it works. I'm able to transfer from the PLC to the PC and I can see the PLC connections to the server in the server window.

Comment: @HansHubertVogts I wanted to try avoiding external programms. I want to keep it with the less amount of things running at the same time. There's already a lot. Thank you for your answer thought!